# Where does Python get the preferred encoding from?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I've just uninstalled all languages on my Windows 10 except for English and set the system locale to English (US). `python` says that my preferred encoding is `cp1252` which is quite the opposite of what I prefer (`utf-8`).

```
C:\Users\nope>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'cp1252'
```

How do I change my preferred encoding to `utf-8`? And most importantly where is `python` getting `cp1252` from?

Comment: You can change this with the `chcp` command on the command line. There are issues with UTF-8 support in the Windows console.

Comment: The better alternative is to upgrade to Python 3.6 where on Windows the default is UTF-8 now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The better alternative is to upgrade to an unreleased version of Python?

Comment: @MartijnPieters First of all, my question is not a duplicate of that question. My question is "Where does Python get the preferred encoding from?". Secondly, I've just installed Python 3.6 and my preferred encoding is still `cp1252`.

Comment: @foxneSs: see https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-528; the *console encoding* is UTF-8. Windows still sets an ANSI codepage for the 'locale' regardless. The `getpreferredencoding()` function on Windows returns the second value from the tuple returned by the [`PyLocale_getdefaultlocale()` C function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/_localemodule.c#l284), where the `encoding` value comes from the Windows API [`GetACP()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070(v=vs.85).aspx). Python 3.6 heeds the warning there and uses Unicode APIs.